# Method to change font size with switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a method with a `switch` statement like this that gets called every time the size of the window gets changed:

```
int fontSup = someBoolean ? 18 : 12;
int fontSmall = someBoolean ? 22 : 15;
int fontNormal = someBoolean ? 26 : 20;
int fontTitle = someBoolean ? 28 : 22;

switch (Window.DeviceFamily)
{
    case DeviceFamily.Phone:
        fontSup = someBoolean ? 18 : 6;
        fontSmall = someBoolean ? 22 : 8;
        fontNormal = someBoolean ? 26 : 12;
        fontTitle = someBoolean ? 28 : 14;
        break;
    case DeviceFamily.Tablet:
        fontSup = someBoolean ? 18 : 8;
        fontSmall = someBoolean ? 22 : 12;
        fontNormal = someBoolean ? 26 : 15;
        fontTitle = someBoolean ? 28 : 17;
        break;
    case DeviceFamily.Desktop:
        fontSup = someBoolean ? 18 : 12;
        fontSmall = someBoolean ? 22 : 15;
        fontNormal = someBoolean ? 26 : 20;
        fontTitle = someBoolean ? 28 : 22;
        break;
}
```

I now thought that there would be a more beautiful and shorter solution for this using a private method. However, here I'm struggling. I could do something like this:

```
private void SetFontSize (ref int fontToChange, bool someBoolean, int firstValue, int secondValue)
{
    // Same switch statement as in the other method
}
```

I'd just have to call this method for every font I want to change. But I don't think this is the most beautiful and easiest way to do what I want. Maybe it's just too early in the morning to think logically.

I also tried this:

```
private int SetFontSize (bool someBoolean, int firstValue, int secondValue)
{
    return (someBoolean ? firstValue : secondValue);
}
```

But in my opinion this isn't really an improvement because I'd just have to change `fontSup = someBoolean ? 18 : 6;` to `fontSup = SetFontSize(someBoolean, 18, 6);`.

Could you please help me to get an appropriate solution?

Comment: I think microsoft provides some common resolutions settings which you can use or programmatically do it yourself.

Comment: In case you want to use xlab or already do it, there is a [FontManager](http://xlabs.github.io/html/class_x_labs_1_1_forms_1_1_services_1_1_font_manager.html) available.

Comment: Switch-method is clean enough imho. For hardcoded parameters. If you store those settings in external (e.g. xml) file, then `Dictionary` is a better option. If you want to call a method, simply pass to it all fonts (as `ref` parameters) and `someBoolean`. You may consider to store all fonts inside some type, then you only need to pass instance of it (without `ref`) instead of 4 fonts.

Comment: I cannot indicate if you are using Winforms or WPF. In case you are using WPF you could achieve your goal by using some DynamicResource-Binding

Comment: Perhaps you can read faster than I can. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Sinatr But I'd have to pass the values to the method too because they are different in each case.

Comment: `int fontSup = someBoolean ? 18 : 12;
int fontSmall = someBoolean ? 22 : 15;
int fontNormal = someBoolean ? 26 : 20;
int fontTitle = someBoolean ? 28 : 22;` is code which doesn't do anything, redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Firstly, encapsulate the font size settings in a class:

```
public sealed class FontSize
{
    public int Sup;
    public int Small;
    public int Normal;
    public int Title;
}
```

Now you can initialise a static `FontSize` and a static `Dictionary<DeviceFamily, FontSize>` somewhere in your class as follows:

```
static readonly FontSize _defaultFontSize = new FontSize { Sup = 18, Small = 22, Normal = 26, Title = 28 };

static readonly Dictionary<DeviceFamily, FontSize> _fontSizeMap = new Dictionary<DeviceFamily, FontSize>
{
    { DeviceFamily.Phone,   new FontSize { Sup =  6, Small =  8, Normal = 12, Title = 14 } },
    { DeviceFamily.Tablet,  new FontSize { Sup =  8, Small = 12, Normal = 15, Title = 17 } },
    { DeviceFamily.Desktop, new FontSize { Sup = 12, Small = 15, Normal = 20, Title = 22 } }
};
```

Then implement a lookup method to return a `FontSize` from a bool and a `DeviceFamily` like so:

```
public static FontSize GetFontSize(DeviceFamily deviceFamily, bool someBoolean)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(DeviceFamily), deviceFamily))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(deviceFamily));

    if (someBoolean)
        return _defaultFontSize;

    return _fontSizeMap[deviceFamily];
}
```

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I was searching for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting I think what matters most is this. Given a boolean value, a device family your dispalyed text should have a given font as set out above. However they aren't proportional to one another. So this switch case is the best way to do it other than some fourier series approximation which would give you the right fonts as a function of the two variables a boolean and device family or to use micosoft code which sweeps the problem under the rug but really does the same thing.